# Group whose order is product of 2 primes

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How it is true that a group whose order is the product of two primes is a cyclic group?

Consider a group of order $6=2\times 3$. I know $O(\mathscr{S}_3)=6$ but $\mathscr{S}_3$ is not cyclic.

Is there some additional info about the result stated above?

Kindly provide the proof for it too.

Comment: The group is guaranteed to be cyclic if the group order is $pq$ , $p<q$ and $p$ does not divide $q-1$

Comment: Ohh,any proof of this result?

Comment: Google Sylow's theorem. This is the key to prove this and similar results.

Comment: Please share your thoughts so far :)